# Waiting For Debugger. Application Actualización del sistema (process android.rockchip.update.service)

Tags: android

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:
Configurando una radio china roadnav s160 para mí coche.
Me ha empezado a salir este mensaje:
Waiting For Debugger. Application Actualización del sistema (process android.rockchip.update.service) is waintig for then debugger to attach.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo y que no aparezca más dicho mensaje?
Gracias

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Hola. Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Esto ocurre cuando intentas depurar la aplicación en el IDE?